# Make a except keep on with the iteration

Tags: python, iteration, try-catch, except

I have the following code

```
list = [2,5,7,8,'$',1,6]

try:
    for i in list:
        print(i+1)
except:
    print('error')
```

The output is

```
3
6
8
9
error
```

But I want it to print the 'error' and then keep on going with the iteration so that the output would be

```
3
6
8
9
error
2
7
```

How do I do that?

Comment: why using try except? Try this in for loop if you don't need to use try-except block: `print(i+1 if isinstance(i, int) else "error")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work:

```
for i in list:
    try:
        print(i+1)
    except TypeError:
        print(error)
```

Putting the try-except block inside the loop allows the loop to continue once the error is found. It's also better to specify the error you are catching in case another one pops up that you are not aware of.